# java.lang.AssertionError: response status is wrong Expected :200 Actual :400

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Im trying to implement a unit test of that method but it always gives me 404 , I dont know where is the problem , here is my method :

```
@PutMapping ("/EditPassword")
    public ResponseEntity<String> EditPassword(Principal principal, @RequestBody Password password ) {
        User u= userService.getUserByName(principal.getName());
        BCryptPasswordEncoder b = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        if(b.matches(password.getOldPassword(), u.getPassword())) {
            u.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password.getNewPassword()));
            userService.editUser(u);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Password Updated successfully",HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Sorry! You're unsuccessfully updated password.",HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED);
        }
    }
```

and here is my test :

```
   @Test
    public void updatePasswordTest() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1);
        user.setPrenom("Oumaima");
        user.setUsername("username");
        Principal mockPrincipal = Mockito.mock(Principal.class);

        when(userService.getUserByName(mockPrincipal.getName())).thenReturn(user);
        user.setPassword("test");
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .put("/users/EditPassword")
                .principal(mockPrincipal)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .contentType(IntegrationTestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(IntegrationTestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(user.getPassword()));

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
        int status = response.getStatus();
        Assert.assertEquals("response status is wrong", 200, status);
    }
```

Comment: Your `RequestBody` is a Password object. I think you need to pass the Password object to `.content`

Comment: Could you share the full code of your class controller? Where you have defined the EditPassword method.